# Azure Cloud Service Disappearing From Azure

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service Worker Role that I'm using to maintain a Lucene Index. The service has been completely removed from Azure twice. The first time I thought someone may have inadvertently deleted, but I don't believe this to be the case. Has anyone else ran into this issue? Are there any logs/dashboards in Azure that may help me determine why this service is completely disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS understands the Importance of your data/service so its highly unlikely that your service will be removed automatically. In order to check about your service you can go to Management Service and check out operation logs within the timeframe when your service was up and now you can filter your service from the results.You can check the Caller ID to check who deleted the service in your case.Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2013/11/26/operation-logs.aspx) for checking logs about Azure Mobile Service.

If above is not the case I highly recommend to contact the customer support immediately they will be able to provide you details about your service and can help you in recovering the service if possible.

Comment: The Manage Service Operation Logs is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.